# How can I concat Two pandas columns and create a new with the row?

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have the following pandas

```
A B C
l 1 4
c 2 5
d 3 6
```

How can I conver that on

```
A E T
l 1 B
c 2 B
d 3 B
l 4 C
c 5 C
d 6 C
```

Thanks

Comment: `df.melt('A')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just want to add a little to @Quang Hoang's answer to complete the solution.

```py
df = df.melt('A')
df.rename(columns={'variable': 'T', 'value': 'E'}, inplace = True)
```